# Microsoft Azure: How to change subscriptions in a script that iterates through resources across multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell

[image: Adding the AzureRm.Profile version detail][image]I have seen similar threads for Azure CLI and I'm using Azure PowerShell console NOT CLI. My understanding is that *Set-AzureRmContext* only sets the context of the script for a given session. Is there a way to switch the context in the middle of the session? Background- I have a script that goes through each resource it is creating and the resources are spread across multiple subscriptions. As it is iterating through rows, I need it to change subscription. I'm doing it by name (would be ideal) Using Set-AzureRmContext in each iteration is not working as I run this. Simple Set and Get AzureRmContext test tells me that it fails to switch subscription context. So not sure how to proceed from here.

**What I am using:**

```
$resourceDetail = Import-csv $inputFile
$index = 1
$resourceDetail | foreach {
    Write-host "checking row $index"
    #subscription check and select
    $row = $_   
    $subscriptionName = $_.subscription
    $location = $_.location
    Write-Host "Subscription Name: $subscriptionName"
    Set-AzureRmContext -subscriptionId $subscriptionName
    Write-Host "subscription scope $subscriptionName"
    index = index +1
}
```

[image]
[image: Image that shows how the context refuses to change]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be able to just switch to a new subscription by using: Select-AzureRmSubscription $AzureSubscriptionName

Comment: @OwainEsau Thanks for the response. I tried both Select-Azurermsubscription and set-azurermcontext but neither have any luck. Thoughts?

Comment: @zigzag If the account you use has the permission of the two tenants and subscriptions?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Thanks. Good question. Yes, I can confirm that the same account in portal UI works just fine and I can create new resources etc.

Comment: @zigzag Sorry not sure then, this is how i have always done it, either by using the -subscriptionid parameter or -subscriptionname

Comment: Can you run this:  get-module azureRM.Profile -listavailable and let me know what version you are on?

Comment: Also try running this and try again: Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -Scope Process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell cmdlet `Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId subscriptionId` to change the current subscription event if the subscription is not in the same tenant. But the important thing is that the subscription which you want to change must be in the same account. The example about changing the subscription here:

[image]

Comment: added another screenshot to clarify that the subscriptions I am trying to connect are all in the same account. Just can't switch. Perhaps my PowerShell module needs update or something else? can't tell what could be causing this.

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6289). It seems the same issue as you. Some ways provide in it and you can take a try.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Link. Here is what fixed the issue for us:
The update of AzureRm.Profile module as someone suggested in the thread you linked also. We were on 5.3.4 and are now on 5.5.2. So right now the select-subscription gracefully changes subscription as we wanted.

Comment: So if the solution is helpful, you can accept it as the answer.